# hideBottomBarOnPush not working on child views

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Pushing using segues with parameter on `performSegues` will hide the bottom bar when `hidesBottomBarOnPush` is set to `true`, the problem is on the child view of the view that has been hidden you cannot show/unhide the bottom bar. Already tried `hidesBottomBarOnPush = false`. Is there any way to unhide the bottom bar when the parent view's bottom bar is hidden.

#### Edit:

If I use the `tabBar.hidden` a small white rect will be shown at the bottom of the view. And also another problem with that is, when I change to another tab then go back to the tab I'm working on, the child view is retained but tabBar becomes hidden.

#### Legend:

- `3rd view controller` - is the `parent view` that push segues.
- `4th view controller` - is the `child view`.

Hoping someone can help me with this problem.

[image: tabBar Problem]

Comment: is the child view the view of another controller? can you show your code snippet

Comment: I've added image, as code for `hidesBottomBarOnPush` can be added or set through IB Storyboard Editor or through `prepareForSegue`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the bottom bar in one particular view controller，and show in others, try this, i think this works better than `hidesBottomBarOnPush`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];
      [self.tabBarViewController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
      [super viewWillDisappear];
      [self.tabBarViewController.tabBar setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: a small white rect will appear at the bottom of the view.

Comment: you tried? and if it's a tableView, the bottom won't be covered any way?

Comment: and what about do both "hidesBottomBarOnPush" and "setHidden"?

Comment: I've already tried that, and also not putting a tableview, but instead a custom introduction view, that's why I needed a fullscreen view without any navbar, tabbar, statusbar.

Comment: what about not pushing but presenting modally? and embed the 4th VC in a navigation controller, and 3rd VC present the nav?

Comment: You have a point, but if I present it modally, then the 4th vc will not inherit the tabBarController and the currently tab item selected index will also not inherited.

Comment: Or you show the third view first and let it present the tab bar view